# Why changing the code page does work with .txt but does not with .csv, while listing files with a batch file?

Tags: csv, batch-file, unicode, cmd, encoding

I have a batch file to list the filepaths of a given directory, and I'd like to save the list in a .csv file. Unfortunately the file names are containing characters like these: *á é í ö ő ó ú ü ű*.
I know that I can change the code table to unicode with `chcp 65001` and this works perfectly when I list the paths into a .txt file, but doesn't work when I'm listing into a .csv.
Here's my batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
chcp 65001

set "in=z:\*.dat"
set "out=c:\munka\output.txt"

if not exist "%out%" type nul> "%out%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/s /o:gn %in%') do (
    >>%out% echo "%%a")​
```

As I said the .txt would give back the real names like: *"z:\Baranya\Kővágótöttös.dat"*

And when using .csv it's : *"z:\Baranya\KĹ‘vĂˇgĂłtĂ¶ttĂ¶s.dat"*

I know it has something to do with the encoding, but I am unsure how to solve it.
Also I am not quite sure if this is the best way to list paths with a batch file, but I've found this solution here on stackoverflow.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: a `csv` is just a plain text file with another extension. It doesn't make any difference whether you write to `file.txt` or to `file.csv`. `type file.txt` and `type file.csv` should give you the exact same result. (Whether Excel interprets it correct, is a completely different question - Microsoft does strange things within Excel)

Comment: When the .csv file is imported into Excel, is it using Unicode UTF-8 encoding? What happens when the .txt file is imported into Excel?

Comment: I see the problem now. The excel was not using UTF-8 encoding, and neither when I imported the .txt file. I had to set it to UTF-8 manually.
Still, is there any way within a batch file to write the files with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: You could start your file with [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) byte sequence instead of `type nul>"%out%"`. You can use `>"%out%" echo XYZ` however there is no general advice what the `XYZ` characters should be as those strongly depend on your system locale (output from registry: `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage"  -v *CP|findstr "ACP OEMCP"`).